# Zoom video in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, video, zoom-sdk

I'm using [InteractiveViewer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InteractiveViewer-class.html) class for zooming a video, but sometimes it does not work, I can almost not zoom in or out. I found a way in which I place one finger slightly before the second one and keep it stationary while the other finger moves. But even then the result is hit or miss. When trying it, my success rate of actually zooming in was about 2 per 5.

Does anyone know how to make it work well?

Here is my code:

```dart
  child: InteractiveViewer(
    scaleEnabled: true,
    maxScale: 4,
    minScale: 0.5,
    child: VlcPlayer(
      controller: controller,
      aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
    ),
  ),
```